# JsTree - selecting a parent node will cause browser to freeze

Tags: javascript, checkbox, jstree, multi-select

I'm using jstree, when I select a parent node (after expanding the parent), my browser freezes and I can't go to console or debugger tools to debug. 
I'm using Chrome as my browser. 
If any additional information is needed, feel free to ask. Thanks

Comment: show your code otherwise no one can guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply removed some data manipulation code in callback function of core.data.ajax and it solved! Apparently I made some mistakes and I was changing node Ids manually and in result, the execution ended up in a loop to load nodes.

Answer (score 0):

> I had the same problem with browser freeze .
>
> If you are using Firebug Firefox, you'll notice the problem from time loading
> of JavaScript files .
>
> so you have to make JavaScript files call firstly by put them inside main page
>
> or before the code script .

Comment: I did that, Firebug showed the execution point was the callback function of core.data.ajax . Tnx for the tip